# Не запускается файл .exe Создал в Launch4j

Tags: java, exe

Пытаюсь запустить файл `exe`.

Использую `Launch4j` 3.12

Файл exe просто не запускается. Никаких сообщений нет.

Вот Launch4j лог:

Version: 3.12 CmdLine: C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar\TheOracle.exe --l4j-debug WOW64: yes Working dir: C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar. Java min ver:
Java max ver:
Bundled JRE: jre1.8.0_211 Check launcher: C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar\jre1.8.0_211\bin\javaw.exe (OK) Main class: sample.Main Info: Classpath not defined. Launcher: C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar\jre1.8.0_211\bin\javaw.exe Launcher args: -classpath "C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar\TheOracle.exe" sample.Main Args length: 154/32768 chars Exit code: 0

Нажимаю на значок Шестеренка в Launch4j, вписываю TheOracle.xml..
.. и в итоге файл TheOracle.exe не открывается..

Из командной строки jar файл нормально запускается:
C:\Users\iService\OneDrive\documents\myDocuments\programming\IdeaProjects\Gracian\EnglishTest\out\artifacts\EnglishTest_jar>java -jar EnglishTest.jar

Почему? Что я делаю не так? Или как узнать, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Означает, что приложение сконфигурировано для использования встроенной в `exe` версии JRE, но встроенная JRE отсутствует или повреждено.

Из чего следует, что очевидно, `exe` неверно собран и встраивание JRE в `exe` произошло как то не так.

Comment: Значит дело в JRE, даже если jar файл в командной строке нормально запускается?

Answer (score 0):

Ура!!! Все дело было в том, что я установил разные версии JDK и JRE. Установил одинаковые и exe запустился наконец-то!!!